# 1C и отправка POST запроса с JSON на сайт

Tags: json, post, 1с

Доброго всем дня. Не могу разобраться с отправкой POST запроса скрипту на сайте данных в формате json из 1С.

В php скрипте просто

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

В 1с

```
    тЗаписьJSON = Новый ЗаписьJSON;
    тПараметрыJSON = Новый ПараметрыЗаписиJSON(ПереносСтрокJSON.Нет, " ", Истина);  
    тЗаписьJSON.УстановитьСтроку(тПараметрыJSON);   
    массивЧегото    = Новый Массив; 
    сЗаказы         = Новый Структура;  
    тДанные = Новый Структура;
    тДанные.Вставить("ЧислоJSON", 100);
    тДанные.Вставить("СтрокаJSON", "test");
    массивЧегото.Добавить(тДанные); 
    тДанные = Новый Структура;
    тДанные.Вставить("ЧислоJSON", 101);
    тДанные.Вставить("СтрокаJSON", "test1");
    массивЧегото.Добавить(тДанные); 
    сЗаказы.Вставить("xxx", массивЧегото);
    ЗаписатьJSON(тЗаписьJSON, сЗаказы);
    strJSON = тЗаписьJSON.Закрыть();

    Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение(ИмяСайта);
    HTTPЗапрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос(ИмяСкрипта); 
    HTTPЗапрос.Заголовки.Вставить("Content-type", "application/json");
    HTTPЗапрос.УстановитьТелоИзСтроки(strJSON,КодировкаТекста.UTF8,ИспользованиеByteOrderMark.НеИспользовать);
    ИмяФайлаОтвета = ПолучитьИмяВременногоФайла("txt"); 
    Соединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(HTTPЗапрос, ИмяФайлаОтвета);   
    ФайлОтвета = Новый Файл(ИмяФайлаОтвета);
```

На выходе в файле ответа имею

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: `тДанные.Вставить` какая жесть этот ваш 1С)

Comment: Согласен. Сам в шоке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем проблемы как таковой не было - было просто незнание и непонимание HTTP заголовков.
Для начала не

```
HTTPЗапрос.Заголовки.Вставить("Content-type", "application/json");
```

А

```
HTTPЗапрос.Заголовки.Вставить("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
```

Во вторых не

```
HTTPЗапрос.УстановитьТелоИзСтроки(strJSON,
```

А

```
HTTPЗапрос.УстановитьТелоИзСтроки("motherFuckerData="strJSON,
```