# 1С отправка POST запроса с параметрами

Tags: php, post, 1с

доброго всем

Хочу на сайте принять POST запрос. Что бы его принять, хочу его отправить из 1С. Проблема в том, что разные решения в интернете, в разных решаются разные задачи и проблемы свои. Чистого решения, что бы научиться - нету.

Подскажите как организовать из 1С отправку POST запроса с параметрами? Не GET а именно POST

```
//site:    https://mysite.com/api
//methid:  POST
//key1:    value1
//key2:    value2
//key3:    value3

//принимаю
<?php
if($_POST){
    print_r($_POST);
}else{
    echo '+++GET+++';
}
?>
```

p.s. ест-но гуглить умею, [это решение для GET](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598633/1c-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, параметры необходимо поместить в Url или в Body запроса. Решение ниже можно доработать для обоих случаев:

```
ПараметрыПодключения = Новый Структура("Сервер, Порт", "example.com", 80);
Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение(
    ПараметрыПодключения.Сервер, 
    ПараметрыПодключения.Порт
);


АдресРесурса = "/api?param1=value";
СтрокаТелоЗапроса = "param1=value&param2=another";

Запрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос(АдресРесурса);
Запрос.УстановитьТелоИзСтроки(СтрокаТелоЗапроса, , ИспользованиеByteOrderMark.НеИспользовать);
HTTPОтвет = Соединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(Запрос);
```